Expo 51 is crashing when using expo-file-system
In expo SDK 50 expo-file-system was working fine. i was able to select and upload images to firebase. but now after updating it to SDK 51 as soon as i try to save the selected image using file-system expo app closes automatically.
i have tried using document picker it works but it is not saving the images in proper format. so my only option is to go with expo-file-system which was working fine in SDK 50.
can anyone help me with this?
thanks!
